# Filtering by a ref's properties in App Engine using Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Hypothetical code:

```
@Entity
public class MyEvent {
  @Id Long id;
  @Index String name;
  Ref<Location> myLocation; 
}

@Entity
public class Location {
  @Id Long id;
  @Index String city;
  @Index String country;
}
```

Is there a way for me to do a filter to find all events within a particular city? This seems like it would need a join, which isn't supported, but I wanted to double check since I can't find a definitive answer.

Also, what is the correct way of structuring the data if this type of filtering isn't possible? Would I need to have a denormalized MyEvent entity with all the fields that I could possibly filter on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the [Objectify documentation](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#refs), Ref properties are more of an Objectify sugar than a Datastore feature. They're stored as Key properties in the Datastore, and so it's not possible to query against the properties of the entity which the key might point to.

If you want to query for events within a city, you could either store the event's city on the event itself and query against that, or query all locations within a city and then query for any events matching those locations (that is, by querying against the location keys, which are stored on the events). A third option would be to make cities into actual entities with a collection-type field of Events. You could also make use of ancestor queries - see the "[Datastore Queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries)" docs for more information.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my hunch. Your suggestion to have a collection-type field of Events or an ancestor query sounds like a good way of getting this done.